# Breaking off /tmp using LVM

Tags: lvm, partition, rhel6

I've recently been put in charge of a RHEL6 server running our NMS. I don't know much about Linux filesystem administration. What I'm needing to do is create a partition for /tmp, instead of having it sit on /. We are using LVM to handle our partitions.

```
#Output of df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             4.0G  1.1G  2.7G  29% /
tmpfs                  16G  116K   16G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             504M   61M  419M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LVusr
                      4.0G  2.8G 1003M  74% /usr
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LVvar
                      9.9G  4.5G  4.9G  48% /var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LVopt
                      252G   11G  229G   5% /opt

#Output of cat /etc/fstab
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on <REDACTED>
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=d13d3a55-39c4-4be8-81b3-3181440961ca /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=d032e7b7-f44e-499f-94e1-58064385108f /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LVusr /usr                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/VolGroup00/LVvar           /var            ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LVopt /opt                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LVswap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
#<REDACTED>:/volumes/nxpool-01/unix-home/home /home  nfs     defaults,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,intr,vers=3     0 0
```

This server has 1TB of RAID5 storage, so space isn't an issue. We have ample unallocated space to hand out, I just don't know how to create the partition using LVM. I started to run into issues of automated backups using /tmp and running out of space, so backups started to fail.

Please let me know if I'm leaving out any vital information.

Comment: You should probably go to the people who put you in this position and ask them for some much needed education on the tools that they are making you use - you desperately need it and will be much better off with it.

Comment: I have never met a distro where tmp wasn't already on a separated partition. Sometimes it's over memory (tmpfs) and sometimes it's on a disk, whether it's lvm or not.

Comment: What is the output of `vgs` `lvs` and `pvs` ?   Oh, this was asked 3 years ago.  I'm sure they are sorted by now.

Comment: /tmp is cleared out between reboots. You'd have to make sure that still happens if you explicitly create a volume for that.

Answer (score 1):

Per advice given, I asked my colleague who knows more than I.

The general outline of what needed to happen:

- `vgdisplay` to see Volume groups
- `lvcreate -L <size> -n <name> <volgroup>` to create a new logical volume
- `mke2f -t <fstype> <path/to/volgroup/<name>>` to create a filesystem out on the logical volume
- `vim /etc/fstab` and add a new entry
- `mount` the new partition

Comment: It won't harm anything, but you likely left files in /tmp on the original partition which are now hidden by the mount.  You would have to do a boot-to-single-user-mode two-step to eliminate them properly.

Comment: Ah yeah I actually got rid of everything there first

Comment: You don't need to boot into single user mode to get to a mount shadowed directory, or even unmount the directory above it. It's much easier to bind mount the shadowed filesystem at its root to a different location and remove files there - as the bind mount will be guaranteed to be a single unshadowed filesystem.